# Remote powershell with SSL issue "The authorization of the user failed with error 5"

Tags: powershell, ssl

I'm trying to connect from a domain joined server (Server 2012R2) to a non domain machine (Server 2019) which also has a CIS Level 1 benchmark applied. We've followed the instructions here [Powershell remoting over HTTPS](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-over-https-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate/) but it's still not working. I've checked that the certificate thumbprint on both sides is OK and it IS but it is failing still. The code being used is

```
$Username = 'remoteServerName\remoteLocalAdminUser'
$Password = 'remoteUserPassword'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList   $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "remoteServerName" -useSSL -scriptblock {Get-Service} -Credential 
$Cred
```

The error message on the client side is

```
[remoteServerName] Connecting to remote server remoteServerName failed with the following 
error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (remoteServerName:String) [], 
PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

and in event log
%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-WinRM%4Operational.evtx
we get the error "The authorization of the user failed with error 5"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does not look like an error in config to me. Access denied means the user you are authenticating with does not have remoting permissions on the target system. Can you test with a local Admin? On the username try .\remoteLocalAdminUser. And also try Get-Credential manually to see if it makes a difference